# Function is not getting read in reactJs even after proper import

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios, mern

I am working on an assignment involving simple auth app in MERN stack. Everything is set just one problem is occurring when I am calling the UpdateUser function from another file it is not getting read/recognized by React. Also, when I import another function from the same file i.e logoutUser, it is working perfectly fine.
**Dashboard.js-File where function is imported**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { logoutUser } from "../../actions/authActions";
import { UpdateUser } from "../../actions/authActions";
import classnames from "classnames";
import M from "materialize-css";
import "react-phone-number-input/style.css";

class Dashboard extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      age: "",
      gender: "",
      dob: "",
      mobile: "",
      errors: {},
    };
    this.onValueChange = this.onValueChange.bind(this);
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.errors) {
      this.setState({
        errors: nextProps.errors,
      });
    }
  }

  onChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.id]: e.target.value });
  };
  onValueChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      selectedOption: event.target.value,
      gender: event.target.value,
    });
    console.log(this.state.selectedOption);
  }
  onDateChange = (val) => {
    val = val.toString();
    this.setState({ dob: val });
    console.log(val, typeof val);
  };
  onMobileChange = (value) => {
    this.setState({ mobile: value });
    console.log(this.state.mobile);
  };
  onUpdateClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const UpdatedUser = {
      id: this.props.auth.user.id,
      age: this.state.age,
      gender: this.state.gender,
      dob: this.state.dob,
      mobile: this.state.mobile,
    };
    console.log(UpdatedUser);
    this.props.UpdateUser(UpdatedUser, this.props.history);
  };
  onLogoutClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.logoutUser();
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    var context = this;
    var options = {
      defaultDate: new Date(),
      setDefaultDate: true,
      onSelect: function(date) {
        context.onDateChange(date);
        // Selected date is logged
      },
    };
    var elems = document.querySelector(".datepicker");
    var instance = M.Datepicker.init(elems, options);
    // instance.open();
    instance.setDate(new Date());
  }
render(){
return(JSX)
}
```

**authActions.js- File from where the function is imported**

```
import axios from "axios";
import setAuthToken from "../utils/setAuthToken";
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";

import { GET_ERRORS, SET_CURRENT_USER, USER_LOADING } from "./types";

// Register User
export const registerUser = (userData, history) => (dispatch) => {
  axios
    .post("/api/users/register", userData)
    .then((res) => history.push("/login"))
    .catch((err) =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_ERRORS,
        payload: err.response.data,
      })
    );
};
//Update User
export const UpdateUser = (userData, history) => (dispatch) => {
  axios
    .post("/api/users/update", userData)
    .then((res) => history.push("/login"))
    .catch((err) =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_ERRORS,
        payload: err.response.data,
      })
    );
};
// Login - get user token
export const loginUser = (userData) => (dispatch) => {
  axios
    .post("/api/users/login", userData)
    .then((res) => {
      // Save to localStorage

      // Set token to localStorage
      const { token } = res.data;
      localStorage.setItem("jwtToken", token);
      // Set token to Auth header
      setAuthToken(token);
      // Decode token to get user data
      const decoded = jwt_decode(token);
      // Set current user
      dispatch(setCurrentUser(decoded));
    })
    .catch((err) =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_ERRORS,
        payload: err.response.data,
      })
    );
};

// Set logged in user
export const setCurrentUser = (decoded) => {
  return {
    type: SET_CURRENT_USER,
    payload: decoded,
  };
};

// User loading
export const setUserLoading = () => {
  return {
    type: USER_LOADING,
  };
};

// Log user out
export const logoutUser = () => (dispatch) => {
  // Remove token from local storage
  localStorage.removeItem("jwtToken");
  // Remove auth header for future requests
  setAuthToken(false);
  // Set current user to empty object {} which will set isAuthenticated to false
  dispatch(setCurrentUser({}));
};
```

[image: Image showing the error]

One more thing to add, when I call the function directly instead of using **this.props.UpdateUser**, it is getting recognized by React and the error is gone too but the content of the function is not executing. **PLEASE HELP I DONT HAVE MUCH TIME FOR THIS PROJECT SUBMISSION**.

Comment: `this.props.UpdateUser` is not the same as `UpdateUser`.

Comment: Unrelated, but important: you're using multiple naming conventions, which is very confusing to readers of the code. In general it's best to be consistent in naming, even if it isn't a conventional pattern.

Comment: I don't see you connecting your component to the Redux store and actions anywhere. Did you just omit that code from your post or does your code simply not do that?

Comment: @Lennholm I have omitted that code from the post.

Comment: @DaveNewton I get it...Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of your imports do anything in this file. They are never called. What gets called are similar functions that are passed down to this component as props from some parent component. In your parent component you are passing `logoutUser` but forgetting to pass `updateUser`. Find the root file where `logoutUser` is imported and add `updateUser` to it.